# Convert anonymously typed list to simple array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wonder if anyone can help.

I am using the following code to retrieve some data from a database and output it as JSON:

```
public ActionResult PieDataPropertyTotalsByStatusSO()
{
    var db = new Coyote_AcquisitionsContext();
    IQueryable<Property> query = db.Properties;

    var propertyTotalsByStatus =
        query.GroupBy(p => p.Status).OrderByDescending(p => p.Count()).Select(pg => new { Status = pg.FirstOrDefault().Status.Name, Count = pg.Count() }).ToList();

    return Json(propertyTotalsByStatus, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This outputs data as follows:

```
[ 
{ "Count" : 1205,
  "Status" : "General Stock (Rejected)"
},
{ "Count" : 816,
  "Status" : "New Introduction"
},
{ "Count" : 653,
  "Status" : "Potential"
},
{ "Count" : 110,
  "Status" : "Completed"
}
]
```

However to save bandwidth (and because this is the format the charting library I am using expects) I need to strip out the keys and just end up with:

```
[ 
[ 1205, "General Stock (Rejected)" ],
[ 816, "New Introduction" ],
[ 653, "Potential" ],
[ 110, "Completed" ]
]
```

I can't find an elegant way of doing it.  I may end up with more or less fields than just Count and Status so I can't use a solution that iterates through on the basis of their being exactly two different fields.

Any help massively appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Corrected the JSON that I am looking to output.

Comment: The structure at the bottom is not valid json - You could output an array of arrays i.e. `[[1205,"General Stock (Rejected)"],...]`. Is that a valid option?

Comment: Yes, my mistake that is what I want.  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired format is not a valid JSON. You could get following instead:

```
[ 
    [ 1205, "General Stock (Rejected)" ],
    [ 816, "New Introduction" ],
    [ 653, "Potential" ],
    [ 110, "Completed" ]
]
```

by

```
var propertyTotalsByStatus =
    query.GroupBy(p => p.Status)
         .OrderByDescending(p => p.Count())
         .Select(pg => new { Status = pg.FirstOrDefault().Status.Name, Count = pg.Count() })
         .ToList()
         .Select(x => new object[] { x.Status, x.Count })
         .ToList();
```

Comment: My mistake, your example JSON is exactly what I am after and I have edited my question above.

However your code gives me the error: " Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types. " Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. You have to make the second part of query (anonymous type to array) using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: That is perfect and solves my issue 100%.  Thanks so much for your help.  Been tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Dictionary in C#.

```
var dataDict = propertyTotalsByStatus.ToDictionary(item => item.Status, item => item.Count);
return Json(dataDict , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me but didnt spend much time investigating as MarcinJuraszek answer is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for your time anyway.